# Sharing Dynamically Allocated Arrays Among Functions in a Dynamic-Link Library

Tags: c, arrays, shared-libraries

I have a C shared library (in my case, a DLL) that is used for function calls in a very procedural way. In other words, the main application (.exe) makes separate function calls to this DLL at different times. I would like to share the same array variable among certain functions in the DLL. There is a function that allocates and initializes the array. There is another function that uses the array for some computations. But these functions are called from the main application separately. So I can't pass the array from the initialization function to another in the DLL, because each function is invoked separately (at different times).

I'd like to avoid using a global variable. I could do that, and statically define the array to have a *large enough* size just to be "safe". But large enough may mean unnecessarily very large. I've seen posts suggesting defining the array in a function, but as a static variable and dynamically allocate it in the initialization function call, but I would still need to have access to the same array in other functions.

What is the best way to keep the code general (i.e., with dynamic memory allocation) while ensuring the same array can be accessed from multiple functions?

**UPDATE**

A few more details after some discussion.

One possible approach would be to keep a handle to the array in the caller (.exe) and pass it to a DLL function when needed. But, from an interface/API perspective, it wouldn't make sense to keep passing this array, because that would require changing function signatures that aren't meant to be changed. The array should really reside in the DLL and be accessible everywhere. I only need to update its contents when calling the initialization function in the DLL. Then the other DLL functions will make use of it internally to the DLL.

Comment: Who decides the size of these arrays?

Comment: There's a macro defined in the DLL (and equivalently in the .exe) that I could use to statically define the array (the "large enough" approach). But again, it'd be a really large array, and that's unnecessary.

Comment: Can you have internal global pointer in DLL, shared between all functions, and then `realloc` it as necessary? It wouldn't be thread-safe though

Comment: I think that would mean allocating/deallocating memory for a global variable, and I haven't seen  evidence to support doing that.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a global variable in your DLL.  You could use an internal getter that insures initialization if you want avoid having to check everywhere that this value is initialized.

Comment: Yeah... I can't think of a way out from using a global variable. But what about calling `malloc` or `realloc` on a global variable? Isn't it problematic?